# can I use Hibernate filtering annotations to filter an entity by child collection content?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity ParentEntity defined as

```
public class ParentEntity
{
   private long id;
   private List<ChildEntity> children;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
   public List<ChildEntity> getChildren()
   {
       return children;
   }
}
```

and

```
public class ChildEntity
{
   private ParentEntity parent;
   private String code; 
   ...
}
```

I understand that using the annotation @FilterJoinTable I can filter parents have a child with a specific code, defined as filter parameter, but
I'm trying to figure how to filter by annotations the parents that have no childern or a child with code as the parameter defined.

Something like SQL:

```
select * from ParentEntity p left join ChildEntity c 
                on p.id=c.parent_id
where p.id in (select p.id from ParentEntity p join ChildEntity c 
                on p.id=c.parent_id where c.code=:code) 
OR p.id  not in ( select parent_id from ChildEntity )
```

or HQL:

```
select p from ParentEntity p join fetch p.childen c 
where p.id in (select p.id from ParentEntity p join p.childen c where c.code=:code) 
OR p.id  not in ( select c.parent.id from ChildEntity c )
```

This because I've a lot of classes with `Parent` or `List<Parent>` as property and each one retreives the `ChildEntity` too, always with the same condition above, so I wouldn't rewrite the same condition on all the queries.

Have you any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Filter clause is directly what goes to SQL where clause.

I think you could try something like:

```
@Filter(name = "childWithCode", 
  condition = "(exists (select 1 from ChildEntity ce where id = ce.parent_id and code='foobar'))")
public class ParentEntity { ...
```

Comment: thank for answer, maybe I haven't been clear, so I've edited my question to be more specific, I don't need a simple filter on code, but the list of parents (without children OR with child with code=:parameter)

Comment: You can add other clauses to filter. Just note that its sql not hql going directly to where part of the query hibernate created.

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way is to simply use a query:

```
String code = ...;

Query query = session.createQuery(
    "select p" +
    "    from ParentEntity p" +
    "    left join p.children c" +
    "    where c is null or c.code = :code"
);
query.setParameter("code", code);
List list = query.list();
```

Then whenever you need the filtered Parents, you run this DAO method.

This is more flexible, because there might be times when you want to retrieve Parents without children. Maybe a business case demands removing children, only to add them later. If you always filter out Parents with no children, then you won't be able to re-add children to those, right?

Comment: thank for answer, maybe I haven't been clear, so I've edited my question to be more specific, I don't need a simple filter on code, but the list of parents (without children OR with child with code=:parameter)

Comment: Ok then. Check my updated query. It left joins children and it only selects parents without children or parents having at least one child with that code.

Comment: Thanks for your query, it's cleaner then mine and it will help me with "@Filter" "@FilterJoinTable" annotations

Comment: your solution doesn't use annotations as "@Filter" and " "@FilterJoinTable" but it's useful